# Connect nearby nodes in geographic graph network

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, geography

I'm building a graph network of rivers. So far, I've created a networkx graph of lat/lon points on rivers. Each river has edges between it's points. However, no edges exist between different rivers in my dataset. Now I want to connect rivers that geographically intersect, so for example here:
[image]

I want to add an edge at the red arrow between the end node on the Missouri river and the nearest node on the Mississippi river.

How can this be accomplished? I could iterate through every pair of nodes, calculate their great-circle distance, and add an edge if it's under the distance limit. This could work but seems slow and I wonder if there's a more built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need to check the leaves of each component (=river), i.e. nodes with degree 1 (i.e. the endpoints of each river arm). If the graph is directed, you can further restrict your search to nodes with either in-degree 1 or out-degree 1, depending how the directionality of the edges corresponds to the directionality of the rivers.

```py
my_leaves = [node for node in G if G.degree(node) == 1]
```

2. You can use `scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point` to efficiently find all other nodes within a specified distance. Then select the nearest node that is not part of the same component as the leaf.

```py
tree = KDTree(my_node_positions)
neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(my_leaf_node_positions, radius=my_cutoff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The snag is that the node on the end of one river might not be 'close' to any node on the other river.  Like this:

[image]

So you must check every leaf node for its distance from the **line** between every pair of nodes on other rivers.

The algorithm for calculating the distance of a point from a line segment is easily found by googling. Note that you do not need any fancy great circle distance calculations - the distances you are interested in finding are sufficiently approximated by assuming a flat plane.

If you have a very large dataset, like maybe all the rivers in North America, you will need to prune the line segments you will check to those in the approximate neighborhood - this can be done by using a quadtree ( see https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree )

**Alternative Approach**

Preprocess your dataset, adding nodes along the lines between nodes that are far apart so that no node is no more than a specified distance from any possible merge point.  This makes the finding of the merge point simpler by looking only at node-node distances rather than node-line segment distances. If you need to this a lot then the cost of pre-processing and the storage for the extra nodes might be worthwhile - however, I cannot image why you would need to this more than once.